# UITableView delegate and datasource in external class does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a simple project, with UITableView added as subview of the current view, and external tableviewcontroller class that make a delegate and datasource.

The problem is that all work correctly excepted delegate didSelectedRowAtIndexPath, when I click in a single row, all tableview become white, here is the code:

MAIN CLASS:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let cont:Tbcontroller = Tbcontroller()
    let tableViewInner = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width-(self.view.frame.width/6), height: 180))
    tableViewInner.scrollEnabled = false
    tableViewInner.separatorStyle = .None
    tableViewInner.allowsSelection = true
    tableViewInner.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cont.type = 1
    cont.setCurrentTableView(tableViewInner)
    self.view.insertSubview(tableViewInner, atIndex: self.view.subviews.count+1)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

EXTERNAL CLASS DELEGATE DATASOURCE:

```
import UIKit

class Tbcontroller: UITableViewController {

var type:Int = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

func getCell() -> UITableViewCell{
    let presentCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    return presentCell

}

func setCurrentTableView(table:UITableView){

    self.tableView = table
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = getCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "ciao"
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 100

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("clicked")

}

}
```

When I click, I do  not see the output "clicked"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that TbController() get deallocated.  `dataSource` and `delegate` properties on UITableView are weak.  Therefor, because you only assign TbController to a local variable and to the weak properties, it will get deallocated.

Also, the UITableViewController already creates a TableView for you.  It is not good practice to "recreate" it.  I would rather make use of the TableView in the UITableViewController and add the UITableViewController's view as a subview to your UIViewController's view.

To fix, you need an instance variable for TbController.

**Sample code with ivar for TbController and making use of Tbcontroller's UITableView.**

```
 import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cont: Tbcontroller = Tbcontroller()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        cont.type = 1
        self.view.addSubview(cont.view)
    }

}

    import UIKit

    class Tbcontroller: UITableViewController {

    var type:Int = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func getCell() -> UITableViewCell{
        let presentCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
        return presentCell

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 4
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = getCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "ciao"
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("clicked")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Carien, it works fine, i changed uitableviewcontroller with:

```
: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```